# Safari div height does not match with line-height

Tags: css, firefox, safari

Try this code:

```css
html {
  font: 16px 'Times New Roman', 'Times';
}

.temp {
  display: flex;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="temp">
  a v b b b b b b b b b b
</div>
```

In Firefox the height of the div is 62.4, which is correct, while in Safari it is 60, which is not what I want.

How to make Safari give 62.4 also?

ps. if the css is

```css
.temp {
  display:flex;
  width: 25px;
  line-height:1rem;
  font-size:1rem;
}
```

Firefox and Safari will give same height: 96.
So does Safari deal with decimal point differently?

Comment: I don't have Safari here, but yes, apparently Chrome rounds 1.3rem to 20 pixels, while Firefox and Edge don't. I'm not sure there's a CSS-only solution.

Comment: There is a nice article on rounding of CSS - https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2010/02/10/rounding-off/

Comment: I always expect Firefox to do rounding but in this case it's Chrome